# How to avoid extra column when writing a csv file?

Tags: r, csv, import, export-to-csv

```
# saving the work as ... data_full.csv
write.csv(data.full, "data_full.csv", col.names = TRUE)

#importing file
data.dir <- file.choose()
data <- read.csv(data.dir, header = TRUE)
```

`data.full` was written as

[image]

but `data` got read as

[image]

Can anyone suggest me a solution, on how to solve this simple problem?

Comment: In your `write.csv` statement use the option `row.names=FALSE`

Comment: thought it was FALSE by default. Thanks for that, it solve the problem. Do I delete this post?

Comment: No, best to leave it in case somebody else has the same issue.

Comment: @AndrewGustar - If the question is to be left, please add your response as an answer so that the question does not go unanswered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `write.csv` statement use the option `row.names=FALSE` to suppress the first column - it is on by default.